# No funciona javac en Fedora 36

Tags: javac

Fedora 36

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 21.9 (build 17.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 21.9 (build 17.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)

$ javac --version
bash: javac: no se encontró la orden...
Una orden similar es: 'java'
```

Comment: Tienes que instalar [openjdk-devel](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/installing-java/) para tu versión de Java. Y lo otro, eso normalmente no funciona con --version, suele ser `javac -help`

Answer (score 1):

probaré y te contesto

```
sudo dnf install java-17-openjdk-devel

Instalado:
  java-17-openjdk-1:17.0.3.0.7-2.fc36.x86_64                                       
  java-17-openjdk-devel-1:17.0.3.0.7-2.fc36.x86_64                                 
  mkfontscale-1.2.1-4.fc36.x86_64                                                  
  ttmkfdir-3.0.9-65.fc36.x86_64                                                    
  xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-33.fc36.noarch
```

¡Listo!

```
$ javac --version
javac 17.0.3
```

Gracias amigo!!!